# How to loop through [] brackets of JSON array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have data like this:

```
$json_data_array = '[
          {
            "id": 1,
            "value": "hr@test.com",
            "label": "teets"
          },
          {
            "id": 5,
            "value": "test@test.com",
            "label": "Test"
          }
        ]';
```

I am sending this in ajax response, now I need to loop through this data how can I?
I have tried this but not working

```
$.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: 'POST',
      data: {'data': data},
      success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
          console.log(value);
           });
        },
        error: function (data) {
        }
      });
```

Comment: What are you getting in `console.log(data);` and `console.log(value);`?

Comment: parse the data? using `JSON.parse()`

Comment: After `data: {'data': data},` add `dataType: "json",`  and check

Comment: worked by giving dataType

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `dataType` attribute to your [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) as **json**, so that your data gets parsed to an object first.

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: 'POST',
  data: {'data': data},
  dataType : "json",
  success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
      console.log(value); //value is an object in this case like {"id": 5,"value": "test@test.com","label": "Test" }
       });
    },
    error: function (data) {
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

On success callback, you need to convert your response to object using `JSON.parse()`.

```
 success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);

    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
    $.each(obj, function(key, value) {
      console.log(value);
    });

 },
```